# Setting up quotes

Tags: punctuation

Can someone please tell me which one is correct?

Club president of the home economics club John Smith commented, “

or

Club president of the home economics club, John Smith, commented, “

Comment: Which do you think is correct and why?

Comment: Hmm I have been using the second one for a while since I am renaming the "club president of the home economics club". But I have also read articles where they simply say things like "Head coach John Smith said,"

Comment: This is more style than grammar, but it depends on if *John Smith* (or *club president of the home economics club*) is restrictive or not. If it is, then, per conventional guidance, there should be no commas; if it isn't, then there should be commas. Is there more than one president of the club? Is there more than one John Smith? If the answer to either is in the positive, then don't use commas. But if there is only one of each, then do use commas.

Comment: You've been using it correctly.  But, like most things in English, this comes down to style.  So they've been using it correctly, too.

Comment: (1) *My friend John is nice, but my doctor John is not.* No commas are used because there are *two* Johns and they are being distinguished by their role. (2) *My parents had two children. My sister, Kate, is older than me.* I only ***have*** one sister, so *Kate* is nonrestrictive (optional), and commas are used.